# Add Auto-incrementing Primary Key Field on a .CSV data import

Tags: python, database, sqlite, import

```
import sqlite3
import csv

current_ID = 1

conn = sqlite3.connect("cities.sqlite")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cities")
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE "cities" (
"City_Name" TEXT,
"Population" INTEGER
)
''')

fname="city.csv"

with open(fname) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
        City_Name = row[0]
        Population = row[1]
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO cities(Name_id,City_Name,Population)
VALUES(?,?)''', (City_Name, Population))
conn.commit()
```

> > Can someone help me to add a new column to my SQL table when I import these two columns, please. There are only two columns of data
> >     in the file and I want to add a third, with a an auto incrementing
> >     I.D.
>
> I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Since the program will always create the `cities` table, the CREATE query should be modified to include any additional columns.

From the [SQLITE Autoincement page](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
>   explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
>   unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
>   use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.

Bottom line, `Name_id` column needs to be added to the CREATE table query and removed from the INSERT query.

FYI the same doc also states:

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>   disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>   usually not needed.